# Is it a good idea to create a new "message table" for each user? Should I worry about performance if I use a single table?

Tags: database-design, mysql

I'm working on an app that will have messages exchange and which have a database with several tables to all users data and preferences but I got thoughtful about the table of messages. I will have about 10k users that will exchange about 500k messages per month.

I have saw some questions in concern of this but are about of tables to store preferences and data, what I consider very different cases. So I was building the logic in this way, creating a table for each user, in a database created only for these message tables, so I can find the messages faster.

I thought: there would be 500k messages to query per month against 40~50 messages per month if having a table for each user.

What do you guys think about this?

Comment: It seems a lot simpler to just have a single table for all messages for all users.

Comment: Table size has minimal impact on retrieval speed when the table is properly indexed.  You need to read up on indexing and how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

500K is not a large number of records for a relational database.  Just use a single table, index the UserID fields, and you shouldn't have to worry about performance.

It is more likely that you'll take a performance hit on the added complexity of one table per user.

**Further reading**
[10.3 Limits on Table Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html)